# How to start over with Git to remove unwanted directories in remote repo

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I have a project. I am the only one working on it so far.

1. I create a remote repo
2. I push the project to remote (to find that .idea/, out/, lib/, src/, and [project].iml are all in the remote branch)

Now my question is: how do I fix this situation so that I can just proceed with `git add .` in the future and have everything work as they should. Please provide step by step help. I have already tried a bunch of things, including "git rm --cache -r .". Whatever I do, adding the directories to gitignore have no effects. So really how can I solve this issue -- given that I am the only user of the repo so far. FYI: I even delete the remote repo but each time I recreate it, the bad files still show up.

I am using Intellij (language shouldn't matter but if you are curious: Kotlin)

---

*UPDATE*

Ok, it's official. Intellij is ignoring the gitignore file. I created a brand new project and ignored all the directories mentioned above. And when I push, they all show up in the remote. To ignore I go to "file>settings>version control>ignored files" and added the unwanted directories there.

Comment: About IntelliJ not obeying .gitignore.... those directories (actually, files in those direcdtories) been added before? What I mean is if they were already been tracked by git (made part of the history of the project)? If that's the case, .gitignore does not hold water. It only works for untracked files.

Comment: As I explain in the *UPDATE* section, even for brand new projects, it still doesn't hold water. Is there a play to find the actual .gitignore file and edit it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there seems to be a bug in this feature from IntelliJ. It is suggested to ignore files using .gitignore file instead. I have just tested it in the latest 2018.3 EAP and I can confirm the configured ignored files in IntelliJ does indeed have no effect. I created a brand new file. IntelliJ version control recognizes it as new and I can commit it.

When I check git status (from command line) it shows it is already a new file, this means it is in the staging area of GIT. This is a result of the following setting:
`version control > confirmation > When files are created > [x] add silently`, as shown in this screenshot:
[image]

When you change this to "do not add" IntelliJ can ignore the files. However I have noticed that you have to register the ignored file in IntelliJ FIRST, before you actually create the file. Otherwise the file will still show up as "unversioned files" when you commit. Once you have registered it first, and only then created it, it will be properly ignored by IntelliJ.

More info:

- Bug reported on IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128585
- Support ticket with more details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000210890-Preferences-Version-Control-Ignored-Files-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-git-